# Should i use webservice connection between LMS and Scorm Player?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, scorm

I have an LMS coded in sharepoint & c#. i want to make my LMS scorm compliant. i'm almost new in this scope. i tried using Sharepoint Learning Kit, but it is not useful for me because its not editable completely as i understand.

After trying to use SLK, i decide to write api adapter between SCOs and LMS because i realized that i need an api adapter  and i didnt find an Api adapter to integrate my LMS..

Should i write Api adapter in javascript which using Webservice connection to LMS?

Please don't recommend to go scorm.com, scorm explained bla bla bla.. there is nothing..

Also I made lots of search in google, there is only one project coded in c# called "DotNetScorm", but i couldnt make it working.

Comment: This tool sounds exactly what you're looking for: http://jcasolutions.com/simple-scorm-lms-adapter

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes, you have to implement the API in javascript, and use XMLHttpRequest to send the information to the server.

Your API has to implement this methods:
GetLastError, GetErrorString, GetDiagnostic, SetValue, GetValue, Initialize, Terminate

The hard part is SetValue, and Commit in my opinion (SetValue has to validate the information that the SCO sends you).

And I'm sorry, I saw that you don't want the links, but to know how this should work, you need to read documentation that is in ADL: http://www.adlnet.gov/capabilities/scorm/scorm-2004-4th#tab-resources

Download the SCORM 2004 4th Edition Specification, and then read the three documents there:

SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_RTE_20090814- this one explains how the SCO plays (what you really want) and how the communication between the SCO and the LMS occurs

To implement the API, will not be sufficient in my opinion, because you need to upload the SCORM packages (basically interpret the imsmanifest.xml file), to do this, you need to read this:

SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_CAM_20090814- understand how the SCOs are packed 
SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_SN_20090814- how to chain content

Good luck